# White space below background cover responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a responsive website but ran into a problem with the background. It doesn't stretch the way it should.

Here's a fiddle with my code: http://jsfiddle.net/8jd1hax4/ 
And here's the bit of my CSS with the background

```
body{
background-image:url('Background.jpg');
background-size: cover;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center; 
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-ms-content-zooming: none;
max-width:100%;
max-height:100%;
font-family: 'Scout', arial, sans-serif;
color:#fff;
}
```

You can best see my problem when you make the fiddle more narrow, the white space appears at the bottom. It also shows the white space on my mobile, which is weird because I added a media query for that size.

Any idea how to get it to stretch all the way to the bottom? I've tried adding a transparent border and padding on the bottom, both to no avail.

Thanks! :)

Comment: I don't see the white space at the bottom when I reduce the width. Are you sure this isn't browser specific?

Comment: Pretty positive! I took a screencap http://puu.sh/aSQwp.jpg in jsfiddle. And here's one in the firefox responsive mode http://puu.sh/aSQAy.jpg

Comment: I see what you mean now (by looking at the result frame itself). It appears the actual <html> element is not taking up the height of the viewport. Did you try just adding *height: 100%* to the <html> element? That will probably take care of it.

Comment: You're completely right. Can't believe I missed that one. Set the height to 100% and it works beautifully! Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

The problem with having the background on the body is that the body is not necessarily the full screen, but only as much of the screen as has content. So when you resize and the content gets shorter, the body gets shorter.

One solution would be to put a wrapper tag around your content:

```
<body>
   <div class="wrapper">
      (All other content goes here)
   </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
   overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
    background-image:url('http://capeanntunaclub.com/images/Background.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center; 
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -ms-content-zooming: none;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow: scroll;
    font-family: 'Scout', arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8jd1hax4/2/

Answer (score 5):

For the record, here's another option for you: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/xrz4v4L4/

The important bit is that I'm setting the background image on the html element, so it's sure to include the full height of the browser window.

```
html { 
  background: url(http://capeanntunaclub.com/images/Background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

The credit for this and other solutions goes to http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/
Good luck!